# Synchronize from localhost to another host which is not the playbook host

Tags: ansible, rsync

I'm running an Ansible playbook for `host_a`. Some tasks I delegate to `host_b`.
Now I would like to use the [synchronize](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/synchronize_module.html) module to copy a directory from `localhost` to `host_b`. But `delegate_to` is the wrong option here, since this results in copying from `host_b` to `host_a`.

Is there a possibility to do that?

```
- hosts: host_a

  tasks:

  - name: rsync directory from localhost to host_b
    synchronize:
      # files on localhost
      src: files/directory

      dest: /directory/on/host_b

    # delegate_to does not work here
    # delegate_to: host_b
```

The only solution I can think of is deleting the target directory and then using a recursive copy with the copy module.

I couldn't find anything in the module documentation.

(Using ansible 2.4.2.0)

Doing this task in its own play for `host_b` is also not really an option because the variables I need for this task depend on `host_a`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution in this case is to use rsync command with [local_action](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation), i.e

```yaml
- hosts: cache1
  tasks:
  - name: rsync directory from localhost to host_b
    local_action: command rsync -az "{{ playbook_dir }}/files/directory" "{{ hostvars['host_b']['ansible_host'] }}:/directory/on/host_b"
```

`{{ playbook_dir }}` helps by not hardcoding paths on local system.